# Want voice input into a TextBox, this code do but only once, (UWP C#)

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, speech-recognition, windows-10-universal

I tried using this code

```
SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();
textBox1.Text = speechRecognitionResult.Text;
```

But it provide output only 1 time but i want to get output continuous till i close it myself.
Please help me how i can do that.

I tried this method but its providing nothing.

```
await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += async (s, e1) =>
{
    if ((e1.Result != null))
    {
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low,() =>
        {
            var result = e1.Result.Text;
            textBox1.Text = result;
        });
        speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Resume();
    }
};
await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync(SpeechContinuousRecognitionMode.PauseOnRecognition);
```

please help,Thanks and must reply. :)

Comment: Appallingly sloppy formatting. Please fix.

Answer (score 2):

To get continuous speech recognition result, you can refer to [Continuous dictation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/enable-continuous-dictation#start-and-stop-recognition). This document describes how to capture and recognize long-form, continuous dictation speech input. You can follow the steps in this document to implement your own. And also, there is an official [Speech recognition and synthesis sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) in GitHub that might help you.

To start the recognition, you can just call [StartAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession#Windows_Media_SpeechRecognition_SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession_StartAsync)
 method as you need speech recognizer continues listening for and processing speech input after a recognition result is generated. And then there will be no need to use `speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Resume();` in [ResultGenerated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn913900) event handler, you can safely remove it form your code.